# How to make a list view widget out of a firestore array

Tags: arrays, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to display my Cart data from firestore into a listview widget but to do so, I need the 'Cart' array's length.

[image: Firestore Database Structure]

How do I build a listview on my app based on the data from the 'Cart' collection?

```
child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .collection('Cart')
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData)
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      else
        return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              ListView.separated(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Cartproductcard(
                        cartItem: snapshot.data[index],
                      ),
                  separatorBuilder: (context, _) =>
                      SizedBox(width: 12),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data
                      .length() 
              ),
```

This is what I am am left with so far, when I tried to run it I got the error:

> "NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class '_JsonQuerySnapshot' has no instance method 'length'.
> Receiver: Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot'
> Tried calling: length())"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your screenshots **`Carts` is not a subcollection under the user's document, but an array field inside the user's document.**

So this code doesn't find any documents (since the `Carts` collection doesn't exist):

```
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Users')
    .doc(user.uid)
    .collection('Cart')
```

You'll instead need to:

1. Read the `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(user.uid).snapshots()`
2. Get the `Cart` array from that document.
3. Loop over the items in that array.
4. Construct the widget(s) for each item from the array.